# Sending MP3 over the internet to a phone via GSM

Tags: php, mp3

How do i send an MP3 file to a mobile phone directly from the internet over a GSM network, Will love to implement this using PHP, every response will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Umm... make a call? Seriously, I can think of no other way to do this that works on all mobiles. You need to add more detail to get software-based answers

Comment: What do you mean by 'sending'? Like in SMS or email, ie the phone user does not explicitly request it?

Comment: @bew, it should come just the same way you receive data via bluetooth. I don't want it to come as a link, instead come as the real data it self may be via SMS or some technology.

Comment: What you want is an MMS. SMS cannot contain audio. Also take note of the restrictions of MMS (filesize is limited).

Comment: Also, no feasible, widely compatible solution in this field will be available for free: The cell phone networks are not an "open market" like the Internet, they are controlled by companies that need to make a profit

Comment: @moontear, pls can you direct me on any MMS resources. Thanx.

Comment: MMS related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805772/mms-gateway-provider-with-php-api-url-callbacks-etc

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, you need to use a [Content Delivery Platform of a GSM provider](http://www.google.com/q=content+delivery+mobile+phones) for this.

I remember researching this a couple years back when mobile content, especially ringtones, had been all the rage. Things might have changed since then (especially with phones having WiFi access), but you had to have a contract with someone that actually has access to the GSM network to send the mobile content to cellphones.

You'd then use this providers API to manage your content and to send it to devices. For instance for the german Deutsche Telekom, there is a [`Zend_Service` package](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.developergarden.html) that allows you to use some of their telecommunication services (for a charge). This particular one doesn't allow sending of digital content like MMS or MP3s, but it might given you an idea what to look for.

**Edit:** try [googling for MMS Gateway](http://www.google.com/q=MMS+gateway) and check with your country's GSM providers

Comment: ... and oh, will this cost you. An arm and a leg won't be enough, you'll have to throw in a kidney or two.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks for your reply, i want to develop this by myself then push it through a GMS network. Using a language like PHP. Is this not feasible. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyberomin probably not, no. To "push" anything you will need the help of the mobile provider in some form. Also, content delivery varies massively between cell phone types, there are dozens of different protocols.

Comment: @Pekka, can you give me any of the protocols.

Comment: @Cyberomin MMS is probably your best bet. You need to specify what countries you want to do this in to get good tips

Comment: @Cyberomin check @Gordon's update. Your best (probably cheapest) bet is to find a MMS gateway directly in Nigeria. Maybe ask the local mobile networks

Answer (score 1):

> directly from the internet over a GSM network

GSM is a low level network protocol, while it is possible to write a stream directly to a port on the device (yes, it uses ports, just like IP) or even compose individual packets, this pre-supposes that you have access to a gateway device in order to do this from an IP connected device. Why bother? It'd be really hard to find a phone which does not support WAP or iMode made in the last 10 years - and there is already an infrastructure and protocols in place to map the internet into the mobile networks (regardless if they are GSM, GPRS, Edge...).

And of course, unlike using a browser on your PC, the WAP protocol allows for push notifications - but this requires the services of a wap gateway (e.g. Kannel) rather than just a simple website.

This would deliver the content **as a file** if you want to stream audio over a telephone conversation - that's something different. Have a look at VOIP/PBX systems e.g. Asterisk

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I am guessing you want to exchange sound files between two people, one on an ordinary Internet connection, the other on GSM. Or else you could just design a mobile-friendly web site where GSM/GPRS users can download their music.

Under this assumption, XMPP (a.k.a Jabber) might be a solution.There are even XMPP libraries for JavaME and most certainly for iPhone and Android. Of course, both users must have an active Internet connection.

Comment: say i have a file stored on some server, i want the file, i put my mobile phone number and click send and the file is sent to my phone, any tips.

Comment: Then MMS is your only option, as others have already mentioned. But sending MMSs is not cheap.

Comment: can u educate me on this, cost is not a problem here, let me know possible gateway that can allow this.